# Using observable in observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I am kinda with observables and I have silly problem with them.

I have 2 observables from my store:

```
  @select() fiches;
  @select() langs;
```

Now I want to filter fiches but depending on langs observable.
I tried something like this:

```
private getFiches(): Observable<Fiche[]> {
      return this.fiches
      .map(fiches => fiches.filter(fiche => fiche.lang === this.langs.lang))
      .do(fiches => console.log(fiches));
}
```

But obviously It cant work like that.

```
export interface Fiche {
    id: number;
    lang: string;
    translation: string;
}
export interface Langs {
    lang: string;
}
```

Comment: Please describe how **exactly** you want to filter `fiches` with `langs` or vice versa.  I'm not clear on what you are trying to do.  What do `fiches` and `langs` represent.

Comment: Updated post, I want to show fiches which have the same lang as in langs observable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest`:

```
private getFiches(): Observable<Fiche[]> {
  return Observable.combineLatest(this.fiches, this.langs)
    .map(([fiches, langs]) => fiches.filter(fiche => /* … */));
}
```

I left out the `/* … */` because it isn't clear to me how you want to filter "an array by an array", but assuming that you do, that's how you can do it.